# trying to click the title and show the paragraph detail

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to make accordion that can hide and show according to the title that i've been clicked. I'm using jQuery to do that

HTML

```
  <div class="panelContainer"><!-- 1ST PANEL-->
    <h2 class="h21">Do I need a website?</h2>
    <p class="contentBox">Morbi hendrerit accumsan orci, tristique aliquam nunc suscipit nec. Vestibulum consequat ornare nunc, ac tristique urna cursus id. Cras eu viverra leo, vitae rhoncus dui. Vestibulum rutrum neque ac risus eleifend luctus. Phasellus ultrices, enim quis dignissim tempus, nibh sem faucibus nisi, at blandit velit massa in nunc. Praesent enim libero, blandit sed massa ut, imperdiet dictum odio. Maecenas sagittis neque a est porta, at feugiat nulla tempor. Cras vitae tincidunt quam, non interdum quam. Sed imperdiet lacus nibh, eget viverra eros porta ut. Nulla sed tellus velit. Nullam quam dolor, malesuada eget bibendum a, lacinia ac ante.</p>
</div>

    <div class="panelContainer"><!-- 2ND PANEL-->
        <h2 class="h21">What is SEO?</h2>
        <p class="contentBox">Aliquam felis orci, varius nec facilisis nec, eleifend ac ante. Donec ligula est, dapibus sed volutpat sit amet, pellentesque id sem. Vestibulum imperdiet volutpat dignissim. Morbi tincidunt lobortis libero et placerat. Pellentesque dignissim diam laoreet, ultricies ligula aliquam, consectetur sapien. Praesent luctus orci in vulputate tincidunt. Aenean fermentum ante non elementum convallis. Sed eget magna enim.</p>
    </div>
```

js

```
var btnTitle=document.getElementsByClassName("h21");
var contentBox=document.getElementsByClassName('contentBox');

for(var i=0;i<btnTitle.length;i++){
    btnTitle[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        var targetSection=document.querySelector(".panelContainer:nth-child(" + (i+1) + ")");
        var targetContent=targetSection.querySelector(".contentBox");
    
        for(let item of contentBox){
            item.style.display='none';
        }
        targetContent.style.display = 'block';
    });

}
```

Comment: What you are using is not jQuery, it's vanilla JS, and it can be simplified by alot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hidden` and `for...of` as well as simple DOM traversal using `nextElementSibling`. This reduces the code necessary to two lines.

```js
for (const toggle of document.getElementsByClassName("h21"))
  toggle.addEventListener('click', () => toggle.nextElementSibling.hidden = !toggle.nextElementSibling.hidden)
```

```css
.h21 { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="panelContainer">
  <!-- 1ST PANEL-->
  <h2 class="h21">Do I need a website?</h2>
  <p class="contentBox" hidden>Morbi hendrerit accumsan orci, tristique aliquam nunc suscipit nec. Vestibulum consequat ornare nunc, ac tristique urna cursus id. Cras eu viverra leo, vitae rhoncus dui. Vestibulum rutrum neque ac risus eleifend luctus. Phasellus ultrices, enim quis
    dignissim tempus, nibh sem faucibus nisi, at blandit velit massa in nunc. Praesent enim libero, blandit sed massa ut, imperdiet dictum odio. Maecenas sagittis neque a est porta, at feugiat nulla tempor. Cras vitae tincidunt quam, non interdum quam.
    Sed imperdiet lacus nibh, eget viverra eros porta ut. Nulla sed tellus velit. Nullam quam dolor, malesuada eget bibendum a, lacinia ac ante.</p>
</div>

<div class="panelContainer">
  <!-- 2ND PANEL-->
  <h2 class="h21">What is SEO?</h2>
  <p class="contentBox" hidden>Aliquam felis orci, varius nec facilisis nec, eleifend ac ante. Donec ligula est, dapibus sed volutpat sit amet, pellentesque id sem. Vestibulum imperdiet volutpat dignissim. Morbi tincidunt lobortis libero et placerat. Pellentesque dignissim diam laoreet,
    ultricies ligula aliquam, consectetur sapien. Praesent luctus orci in vulputate tincidunt. Aenean fermentum ante non elementum convallis. Sed eget magna enim.</p>
</div>
```